# Find the GROWTH RATE of FaceValue for 5 days in percentage

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to open another column and find the growth rate of the facevalue column per day in percentage

| Day | FaceValue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ₦72,077,680.94 |
| 2 | ₦112,763,770.99 |
| 3 | ₦118,146,250.01 |
| 4 | ₦74,446,035.80 |
| 5 | ₦77,026,183.71 |

here is the code but it's not working

```
value_performance%>%
  mutate(change=(value_performance$FaceValue-lag(FaceValue,5))/lag(FaceValue,5)*100)
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI, phrases like *"it's not working"* with nothing further does not help: if you get errors/warnings/messages, *show them*; if you get incorrect values, *show them* and explain why they are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three problems:

1. `FaceValue` appears to be a string, not `numeric`, try first fixing that with `as.numeric`;
2. (Almost) never use `value_performance$` inside of a `dplyr`-pipe verb. ("Almost" because there are rare times when you need it. Otherwise you are at *best* being inefficient, possibly using incorrect values depending on what is happening in the pipe before its use.); and
3. You say *"per day"* but you are lagging by 5. While I'm assuming your real data has more than 5 rows, you are still not calculating by-day.

Try this.

```r
value_performance %>%
 mutate(
   FaceValue = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", FaceValue)),
   change = (FaceValue - lag(FaceValue))/lag(FaceValue)
 )
#   Day FaceValue  change
# 1   1  7.21e+07      NA
# 2   2  1.13e+08  0.5645
# 3   3  1.18e+08  0.0477
# 4   4  7.44e+07 -0.3699
# 5   5  7.70e+07  0.0347
```

Answer (score 0):

With similar data:

```
Day <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
FaceValue <- c(72077680.94, 112763770.99, 118146250.01, 74446035.80, 77026183.71)
df <- data.frame(Day, FaceValue)

df
df %>%
  mutate(change= 100*(FaceValue/lag(FaceValue)-1)
         )
```

Results in:

```
  Day FaceValue     change
1   1  72077681         NA
2   2 112763771  56.447557
3   3 118146250   4.773234
4   4  74446036 -36.988236
5   5  77026184   3.465796
```

Not sure what is wrong. Maybe check your data classes and make sure `FaceValue` is numerical.